# yii2 : how to return image with response->data

Tags: yii, yii2

```
public function actionFind()
    {
    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    \Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    \Yii::$app->response->headers->add('content-type', 'image/jpg');
    $img_url = file_get_contents('images/ab.jpg');
    Yii::$app->response->data($img_url);
    return \Yii::$app->response;
    }
```

why this code has error??

error is : 
cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: show the error  please ..  and you code  .. is not enough .. add the  action/function code  ..

Comment: cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: i tested with :      $img_url = file_get_contents('images/ab.jpg'); and again i have error

Comment: i want created link such as this link : http://manage.pyra.ir/show_advertiser_pic.php?id=58&w=1200&h=500

Comment: if you need  the link why you are loading the image ..  you should assign the path only

Comment: i need link with( content image) and (jpg header!)

Answer (score 2):

data is property, not function http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$data-detail

```
public function actionFind()
{
    $response = \Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $response->headers->add('content-type', 'image/jpg');
    $img_data = file_get_contents('images/ab.jpg');
    $response->data = $img_data;
    return $response;
}
```